# How to Convert Fortran MAX(0D0, X) to Another Language

Tags: fortran

In the code I am converting, both x() and x() are vectors of the same length.  The MAX function I came across looks like:

```
v = MAX(0D0,x)
```

then the v vector is used like:

```
v = v*N/SUM(v)
```

I am thinking that MAX will return a vector filled with essentially Math.Max(x(i),0) for each element of x?  It appears to be a method to zero out any negative reals which could be in the vector x?

Comment: If you did read about it, the behaviour you wanted to confirm must have been there. I just wanted to prevent another wave of read-the-fortran-manual questions every few hours once you find a line you did not immediately understand. Also, I am no moderator, moderator is the person that deleted my previous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right because the `max` function is "elemental" (= works in an element-wise manner), e.g.,

```
program main
    implicit none
    real x(4), v(4)

    x = [ -1.0, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0 ]
    print *, "x = ", x

    v = max( 0.0, x )

    print *, "v = ", v
end
```

gives

```
 x =   -1.00000000     -0.500000000      0.500000000       1.00000000    
 v =    0.00000000       0.00000000      0.500000000       1.00000000
```

For more details, please check these docs pages:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MAX.html

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/m-to-n/max.html

http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfpro78help/F95ARMAXFn.htm

In particular, the last page says:

> If any of the arguments are arrays, the result is an array with the same shape. Each element of the result is as if the scalar MAX function was called for each corresponding element of the array argument(s).